# Not able to figure how to write if-else statement for one of the user defined cases in python

Tags: python, api

I have two API.

1. Australia API- This API works only for year 1985 to 2024.
2. USA API- I wanted this API need should work only before 1985.

Taking 4 things from user.
-Start Year
-End Year
-latitude
-longitude
sample command: python test.py -latitude '' -longitude '' -startYear '' -endYear ''

User can enter 3 ways of input.

Case 1. Start year=before 1985, end year= After 1985 ---->both AUSTRALIA and USA api run.

Case 2. Start year=At 1985 or later, end year= after 1985 ---->only AUSTRALIA api should run.

Case 3. Start year=before 1985, end year=before 1985 ------>only USA api run

**Problem is that I am not able to figure out how to write the code for Case 1 after writing the code for case 2(Australia API) and case 3(USA API).**

```
import requests
import json
import argparse
import time
import pandas as pd
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Process some integers.")
parser.add_argument("-latitude", help="Latitude(Degress)")
parser.add_argument("-longitude", help="Longitude(Degress)")
parser.add_argument("-startYear", help="Start of the Year")
parser.add_argument("-endYear", help="End of the Year")
parser.add_argument("--verbose", help="display processing information")
start = time.time()
def main(latitude,longitude,startYear,endYear,verbose):
    parameters = {
        "latd": latitude, # [deg]
        "latm": 00, # [deg]
        "lats": 00, # [deg]
        "lond": longitude, # [deg]
        "lonm": 00, # [deg]
        "lons": 00, # [deg]
        "elev" : 00, # [km]
        "year" : None, # [YYYY]
        "month" : '07', # [MM]
        "day": '01', # [DD]
        "Ein": 'D'  # [Model]
    }
    hostname = "https://api.geomagnetism.ga.gov.au/agrf"
    hostname1 = "http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag-web/calculators/calculateDeclination?%s"
    df_1=pd.DataFrame()
    for year in range(startYear, endYear):
        if (startYear>=1985 and endYear>1985):
                
        -----
        elif (startYear<1985 and endYear<1985):
           -------
```

Comment: If the condition outlined in the `if` and `elif` covered both case 2 and 3, wouldn't just add a `else` block cover the case 1?

Answer (score 0):

```
if endYear < 1985:
    if startYear < 1985:
        # Case 3
elif startYear >= 1985: 
    # Case 2
elif startYear < 1985:
    # Case 1
else:
    # Case where endYear < 1985 and startYear > 1985 (probably an input error)
```

Comment: Answer's are great. But please provide an explanation. You only posting code makes the OP and future commers copy and paste your answer without understanding the logic behind the answer. Please provide an answer with some explanation. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

```
if end > 1985:
    australia
    if start < 1985:
        usa
else:
    usa
```